# Is there a RAM test for Android devices?

Tags: hardware, ram, system

I need to fix a friend's phone this evening that has suddenly produced loads of android.process.media and com.google.process.gapps errors.  I am going to reinstall the OS as it's an older ROM but it got me wondering: there is `memtest` for x86 based devices that will test the RAM of a PC, is there a similar app that can be loaded in place of an OS on Android that will do the same thing?

Comment: Not that I know of, for starters MemTest x86 is specifically orientated *obviously* to x86 architecture. None such thing exists for ARMv6 or ARMv7 architecture! The reason you're getting force closes there - has nothing to do with RAM chips, rather, a app that was installed somewhat crashed the dalvikvm's cache which produces the neglible effect, or possibly modified a framework portion to add extra icons and whatnots and re-flashed it back in or pushed it into the handset...

Comment: I loaded a fresh ROM to the device and have not had a recurrence of the issue.  I still feel this question has merit in that it might someday be answered -- I know of no hardware diagnostics, be it for ARMv6, ARMv7, or any other potential architecture.  It would be useful.

Comment: In all fairness, the controls and regulations involved in producing RAM chips is quite high and there would be no room for errors that would be tolerated either (think of equivalent Intel's pre-fabrication factory...) Devices like smartphones with their RAM chips tightly integrated, are not going to fail. SO I think your question is not a real question and not constructive either. As you have found out, a simple wipe/flash of the ROM cured the hiccup and has **zero** to do with RAM chips!!!

Comment: Sorry tm, but obviously you know only little about integrated circuits. Of course the memory of a handheld device can fail. It is in this respect no different than any other memory. The reason why there are no testing utilities are not clear to me either. I guess that most people would not bother to check but just claim their guarantee. Also, these tools run typically at boot time, so the phone must be put in recovery mode - also not very attractive when you can just exchange the device.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any tool like `memtest86` for ARM architecture. Related: [How to disable bad RAM addresses and fix bad storage blocks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216337/218526).

Answer (score 1):

This tests RAM, storage and well many other device features: [Phone Check (and Test)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inpocketsoftware.andTest)

Comment: Apps can't test hardware resources without root access. All they can do is either rely on system provided APIs to get AMAP information about hardware, or perform a stress test within the limitations enforced by OS. So they can't estimate performance correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Like to point out that Apps most definitely can test hardware without root access. Bad memory can be traced via stress tests even within OS limitations, although not pinpointed but to know if its bad or not its quite useful.