# Boot-Up System Test tools

Tags: adb, python

I am a test automation script developer using Python.  One of my recents tasks has been to create scripts that can output the following test cases from an Android device under test during boot-up:

-Identification - SW Ver, SN, CPU, memory,....

-Memory test - bad block count

-DDR Training

-Peripheral inventory check

-Error logging

Ideally, this would all be done via adb interface, but I don't know what tools or commands are available to do such tests.  Some are trivial such as SW ver, SN.  But others like the memory test, and ddr training are new to me.
If anyone can point me in the right direction in terms of adb commands and/or test apps, that would be great.
I'm not an Android developer nor do I know Java so my knowledge of the inner workings of Android is very sparse.

Comment: Android die more a special Linux system, you will not need Java. Try the `getprop` command for identification data. For the rest we can't help you as such data is not available in general Android.

Comment: maybe interesting / related
[How to disable bad RAM addresses and fix bad storage blocks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216306/how-to-disable-bad-ram-addresses-and-fix-bad-storage-blocks)

Comment: [logcat](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logcat/info) or dmesg is available via adb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long until my eMMC is dead?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/525525)